# On using multiple languages for a singular code golf submission

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf, answers, scoring

I was wondering if it were possible to use multiple languages in the same submission. Not a polyglot, but using each of the languages. I have two thoughts on this.

1. One language invokes the other. Let's say we have a Ruby + JavaScript solution. Then, you could have, say, `puts %x(node a)` in `run.rb` and `console.log(x=>x)` in `a`, and have `rub.rb` be the main solution.
2. Alternatively, each language could read the output of the previous language as input. E.g., invoke like `<input> | <language a> | <langauge b>`.

How would these be scored? How would it be consistent, concerning the usage of langs (e.g. multiple usages of the same lang)? How would it compare with each of its component languages? Should it be allowed at all? If not, why not?

---

Here is an example of a multi-language submission, using method 2:

## J + Ruby, idk bytes

Ruby, `ruby.rb`:

```
p gets.split.map(&:to_i).map{|s|s+4}
```

J, `j.ijs`:

```
exit echo 1+i.10
```

Invoke like:

```
j.ijs | ruby.rb
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: Seems dubious, but I can't come up with a concrete why of why this is bad.

Comment: Would this ever be useful?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Maybe, maybe not. It might be fun. Is BF useful? :P

Comment: I feel like method 2 is a bit of a foul, the specialized invocation adds something not provided by either language. If method 1 is done from within a single file then maybe that's a feature?

Comment: This happens all the time with bash answers that also use [sed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65300/triangulating-text/65493#65493), [awk](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/81256/color-count-sorted-by-occurences/81290#81290), [dc](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53683/through-the-bases/53708#53708), or [bc](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18633/print-a-sinusoidal-wave-vertically/18752#18752), for example.

Comment: The dupe target specifically says it isn't concerned with scoring, so I'm reopening this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, it's perfectly valid

The byte count of the solution would be the sum of the byte counts of any files involved, plus the length of any special invocations needed.

For your first example, you have this:

```
//run.rb
puts %x(node a)

//a
console.log(x=>x)
```

This would be invoked as `ruby run.rb`, and would be in the language `Ruby + nodeJS`, with a byte count of **32**, assuming no trailing newlines in the files.

For your second example, you could have something like this:

```
python -c 'print range(10)' | node -e 'console.log(x=>x*x)'
```

In this case, the byte count would be:

- 15 bytes for the Python 2 program (`print range(10)`)
- 32 bytes for the non-standard invocation for a Python 2 program ( `| node -e 'console.log(x=>x*x)'`)

*or*

- 19 bytes for the nodeJS program (`console.log(x=>x*x)`)
- 30 bytes for the non-standard invocation for a nodeJS program (`python -c 'print range(10)' |` )

So, the byte count would be either **47** (counting Python 2 as the primary driver) or **49** (counting nodeJS as the primary driver). You would then choose the byte count more optimized for the scoring criteria (the 47 for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), for example). The language for this submission would be `Python 2 + nodeJS + sh` (the `sh` is included because of the piping on the command line).

Comment: In the second scenario, one might want to golf it like `python -c 'print range(10)'|node -e 'console.log(x=>x*x)'`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Sure, but I'd rather have readable examples over fully-golfed examples.

Comment: Cool, just wondering.

Comment: Bash answers do this all the time, invoking stuff like awk or bc. Yet they are often called just "bash".

Comment: @Pietu1998 I think that's because usually all the code goes in the .sh file

Comment: @MartinEnder True.

Comment: @Pietu1998 they're often called `bash + GNU Utils` because that is more correct. I've also seen just bash called `pure bash` to make the distinction that it isn't using GNU utils.

Comment: Should most `bash + GNU Utils` answers be called `GNU Util with a non-standard invocation` then? This would save them at least the bytes for the name of one of the Utils.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd count the program as either 47 or 49 bytes. `python -c 'print range(10)' | node -e 'console.log(x=>x*x)'` is 59 bytes long (less after stripping spaces), and *that* is the actual program. Shell scripts call different programs all the times, and they're never scored as *commands to the first program plus pipe* or something like that.