# Batch - Can we call another script?

Tags: discussion

Just like the title, can we call another external script if that saves some bytes?

Comment: Yes, but your language becomes `Batch + <NameOfScript>`

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/on-using-multiple-languages-for-a-singular-code-golf-submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, in certain cases

You can't call another script you write yourself, but executing another *scripting language*, or any other publicly available program is fine. All that means is that you have to add the name of the language to the languages your submission uses, e.g. instead of:

## Batch, 26 bytes

it would be something like

## Batch + Perl, 26 bytes

Comment: You also need to include any special invocation bytes.